# Declare array generated with GENERATE_ARRAY in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to set the values of an ARRAY to the result of GENERATE_ARRAY in Bigquery

```
DECLARE arr ARRAY <INT64>;
SET arr = (SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100,10));
```

But I am getting this error

```
Query error: Cannot coerce expression (SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100,10)) to type ARRAY<FLOAT64>
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
DECLARE arr ARRAY <INT64>;
SET arr = GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100,10);
```